# Kotlin Sort list by Timestamp and then by enum

Tags: android, list, kotlin, sorting

I want to sort a list first by timestamp ( just a string in my case) and after that by an enum.

Sorting the list only by timestamp I use

```
list.sortByDescending { it.timestamp }
```

or

```
list.sortWith(compareByDescending<InboxItem> { it.timestamp })
```

For enum I found:

```
list.sortBy{it.enum}
```

I tried to combine both but it does not seem that it will sort by my enum value.

```
list.sortWith(compareByDescending<InboxItem> { it.timestamp }.thenBy{it.enum})
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: It should work the way you write it. Maybe could you provide an example list, and what you expect to happen and what it actually gives? My gut tells me that all timestamps are simply different. The sort by enum only happens between items with identical timestamp

Comment: Thanks a lot! I switched the sorting : First by enum and then by timestamp. And added "ordinal" to enum. list.sortWith(compareByDescending<InboxItem> { it.enum.ordinal }.thenBy{it.timestamp}) . Now it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted will sort the way you described. Note that the default sorting order of enum constants is by *ordinal* (the order they are in the source file), not by *name*. And note that the timestamp order will always win, even if there is a very minor difference of nanoseconds.